# get shipping cost separately for payment gateway in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm building a custom payment module which i need to pass the product prices (sub total), tax and the shipping cost separately so the gateway will create and email an invoice for the user.

i managed to find how to get the sub total using `$this->cart->getSubTotal()`

and the taxes using `$this->cart->getTaxes();`

but i cant find how to get only the shipping cost

can someone tell me how can i get shipping cost selected for that order separately so i can pass to the payment gateway

Comment: Have you found out to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to know logic of Open Cart 
http://docs.opencart.com/developer-guide

each controller model view language is extend to each object.

[image: Open cart logic]

find the shipping would be checkout shipping info api/shipping

look at all shipping at the cart hint

```
                // Shipping Methods
            $json['shipping_methods'] = array();

            $this->load->model('extension/extension');

            $results = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('shipping');

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                    $this->load->model('shipping/' . $result['code']);

                    $quote = $this->{'model_shipping_' . $result['code']}->getQuote($this->session->data['shipping_address']);

                    if ($quote) {
                        $json['shipping_methods'][$result['code']] = array(
                            'title'      => $quote['title'],
                            'quote'      => $quote['quote'],
                            'sort_order' => $quote['sort_order'],
                            'error'      => $quote['error']
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
```

this controller of the checkout is the success process of the transaction

```
catalog/controller/checkout/success.php
```

here is the last confirmed payments made and clear the session post confirm payment for the next transaction.

Comment: Were you answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were looking for this, For opencart 2.x

```
$data['totalshippingcost'] =  $this->session->data['shipping_method']['cost'];
```

Regards